# Parsing xmlhttp.responseText

Tags: php, javascript, ajax

How can xmlhttp.responseText be parsed? I saw somewhere that the split function can be used for this. Is this the only way or is there a better way? Right now, what's being stored in responseText is being sent to ONE HTML textbox, but I'm trying to parse the xmlhttp.responseText so that I can populate multiple textboxes from the parsed data.

Main page code:

```
function loadDoc()
{
   var xmlhttp;

   // code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
   if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
   {
      xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
   }
   // code for IE6, IE5
   else
   {
      xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
   }

   xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function()
   {
      if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200)
      {
         var doc = window.document.createElement("doc");
         doc.innerHTML = xmlhttp.responseText;
         document.getElementById("textbox").value=doc.innerHTML;
      }
   }

   xmlhttp.open("GET","loadTextBox.php?id=4",true);
   xmlhttp.send();
}
```

loadTextBox.php code:

```
<?php
---Placeholder for correct DB login info---

$result = $mysql->query(---Place holder for correct SQL query---);

while ($row = $result->fetch_object())
{
   $queryResult[] = $row->present_tense;
}
$textboxValue = $queryResult[0];
$textboxValue2 = $queryResult[1];
echo $textboxValue;
echo $textboxValue2;
?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<?php
---Placeholder for correct DB login info---

$result = $mysql->query(---Place holder for correct SQL query---);

while ($row = $result->fetch_object())
{
   $queryResult[] = $row->present_tense;
}
$textboxValue = $queryResult[0];
$textboxValue2 = $queryResult[1];
echo json_encode(array('first'=>$textboxValue,'second'=>$textboxValue2));
?>
```

For your responseText, you can use:

```
function loadDoc()
{
   var xmlhttp;

   // code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
   if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
   {
      xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
   }
   // code for IE6, IE5
   else
   {
      xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
   }

   xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function()
   {
      if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200)
      {
         var doc = window.document.createElement("doc");
         var a = xmlhttp.responseText;
         a = JSON.parse(a);
         document.getElementById("textbox").value=a.first;
         document.getElementById("textbox2").value=a.second;
      }
   }

   xmlhttp.open("GET","loadTextBox.php?id=4",true);
   xmlhttp.send();
}
```

Comment: Nothing gets populated in the textboxes using your code. The code needs to be modified to account for EACH textbox. So I'm thinking document.getElementById would be used multiple times for different textboxes by their IDs, but I'm not sure how to do this. Maybe the split function is the way to go?

Comment: Try debugging by alerting xmlhttp.responseText. It's possible that $textboxValue and $textboxValue2 are empty.

Comment: But isn't the line document.getElementById("textbox").value='First Box: '+a.first+'<br />Second Box: '+a.second; only going to be modifying ONE textbox?

Comment: Hi! You can change it to document.getElementById("textbox").value+='Content' - so that text will be appended.

Comment: I don't want the text appended for the same textbox.  I want to parse the xmlhttp.responseText so that I can populate DIFFERENT textboxes with the parsed data not the same textbox.

Comment: then use another textbox. document.getElementById('textbox1').value=a.first; document.getElementById('textbox2').value=a.second; in your PHP, just follow how 'first' and 'second' was pushed to the array so that you can access them in javascript

Comment: I used the value=a.first and value=a.second idea, and that part seems to work; however, after alerting xmlhttp.responseText it shows $textboxValue2 is null. Maybe this is why nothing is getting populated for either textbox? There are actual values in the database, so I know that's not the problem. The only thing I can think of involves a foreign character. The value that is supposed to be stored in $textboxValue2 is radiš. The symbol above the s is a caron. Any ideas?

Comment: i believe this can help you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9847816/jquery-ajax-responsetext-character-encoding. If you have any more questions, I suggest that you open another question. I was already able to answer your concern about parsing the response text. StackOverflow discourages extended discussions in comments. :)

Comment: Actually, you were not able to really answer my question since my textboxes are still not populating. I tried a value without the foreign character, and the textboxes still don't populate even though nothing is null this time. I don't see anything wrong with follow-up comments. If a person can answer your question, they may be able to help with other questions building off the original question.

Comment: I have now edited your post with my specific problem and the solution. After it has been peer reviewed I will accept the answer.